# How can I read lines from a text file into a variable

Tags: c++, struct, fstream

I know that there's many questions here about reading lines from a text file and storing it in a c++ struct. However, those questions all contain text files that have precisely the information they needed, such as a text file with :

```
Tom 123

Jim 234
```

However, what if my text file had something like

```
// The range of 'horizontal' indices, inclusive
// E.g. if the range is 0-4, then the indices are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
GridX_IdxRange=0-8

// The range of 'vertical' indices, inclusive
// E.g. if the range is 0-3, then the indices are 0, 1, 2, 3   
GridY_IdxRange=0-9
```

How would I be able to get just the numbers 0-8 and 0-9 besides the equal sign in gridX and gridY to be stored in my struct?

What I tried:

```
struct config {
    int gridRange[2];
    int gridX;
    int gridY;
    int cityId;
    int cloudCover;
    int pressure;
    std::string cityName;
};
```

```
    config openFile(std::string filename, config &con) {
    std::fstream inputFile(filename.c_str(), std::fstream::in);
    if (inputFile.is_open()) {

        std::string line;
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            while (std::getline(inputFile, line)) {
                inputFile >> con.gridRange[i];
                std::cout << con.gridRange[i]; //to show what is stored in the array
                
            }
        }

        //std::cout << range << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
        return con;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Unable to open file" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Ignore the other variables in the struct as I still do not need them yet. The output I got was

```
// The range of 'horizontal' indices, inclusive
0
```

Comment: You would have to read everything, and then just not save the parts that is not  interesting. Perhaps the name to the left of the equal sign should be used to decide which variables the values belong to?

Comment: I see, but how do I do that? I tried changing `while (std::getline(inputFile, line))` to something like `while (std::getline(inputFile, line, '='))` since I can only put one character there, but it still prints out everything although it removed the = sign

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by adding in `if (line[0] != '/' && !line.empty()) {` inside the `while` loop and creating a new string variable called `lineArray[5]`. The function now looks like this

```
    config openFile(std::string filename, config &con) {
    std::fstream inputFile(filename.c_str(), std::fstream::in);
    if (inputFile.is_open()) {
        std::string line;
        std::string lineArray[5];
        int count = 0;
        while (std::getline(inputFile, line)) {
            if (line[0] != '/' && !line.empty()) {
                lineArray[count] = line;
                count++;
                }
            }
        std::cout << "Printing out " << lineArray[0] << std::endl;

        std::cout << std::endl;
        return con;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Unable to open file" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

And the output I'll get is `Printing out GridX_IdxRange=0-8`.